# Are Boxer Engines Easy to Work On?

Tags: engine, maintenance, subaru

How hard are boxer engines to work on and how common are they?

Specifically, I'm looking at a [Subaru Impreza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaru_Impreza#First_generation_.281992.E2.80.932000.3B_GC.2C_GF.2C_GM.29) with a [1.6L EJ16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaru_EJ_engine#EJ16) [boxer engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-four_engine) ( which seems to be in very good condition ) and am wondering how difficult it would be to either work on it myself or find a mechanic who is familiar with this type of engine other than at a Subaru dealership.

Comment: We have a lot of Boxer boys here, @Rory Alsop

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Boxer Brief! To Robert - the biggest issue working on the boxer in the Subaru is getting at the head bolts while the engine is still in the car. I believe most everything else is about the same as any other vehicle. I will leave it to the Subie experts to actually make an answer on this though.

Comment: You would also need to consider pricing and availability of parts where you live. I have had to change a radiator on a 2.0L ... that price hurt! :-(

Comment: All motor's have pro's and con's.  If this were a straight 6 DOHC it would have two cams to time.  This one is essentially a flat v-four so you have 4 cams to time.  If you had an old Dodge Dart, you would have one.  I think the answer is too subjective, it depends on experience and knowledge.  For some, this is a no brainer, for others...total pain.  I will say that most of the Subaru mechanics I meet fall into a different demographic and tend to be more thoughtful and fact based than most which is heartening.  Plenty of highly qualified Subaru guys out there.

Comment: @DucatiKiller I consider myself a novice.  The only engine I've really worked on a bit has been the Mazda 1.8L BP DOHC.

Comment: It's too subjective for me.  I believe there are other more qualified resources here to perhaps quantify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is subjective, but I can share some of my own experience in working with Subarus.

The difficulty level of working on these engines will be defined by your mechanical ability and the type of work you plan on doing. Routine maintenance is fairly easy. The engine bay is easy to get around in my opinion, but it may take some getting used to. Naturally aspirated (non-turbo) engines are generally easier to work on as there are less components at play and more space under the hood.

In regards to maintenance, the following procedures are pretty straight forward:

- Changing oil/oil filter
- Transmission fluid, rear differential fluid, power steering fluid
- Radiator fluid and hoses
- Air intake/air filter
- Exhaust system replacement
- O2 sensor replacement

One thing that is somewhat difficult is replacing the spark plugs which plenty have complained about doing the first time. The spark plugs are located on the sides of the engine which makes them hard to get at. I managed replacing them on an 02 Impreza WRX without going underneath the car or anything crazy.

I can also say that the support community is huge for these cars. You can most likely find anything you need in the many online forums. In North America, it is easy to find shops that are quite familiar with Subarus (sorry, I am not sure about your location). [Here](http://forums.nasioc.com/forums/showthread.php?t=533787) is a great source to start for information, tutorials and faqs for any year Impreza.

Comment: The support community is huge - I get fairly quick responses to things I post in the NASIOC forum and also the http://www.subaruforester.org/ forum. Really helpful folks in both forums. As well, there are a large number of third-party suppliers for engine parts, exhaust, suspension and various other items.